# shmop/PHP on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, shared-memory

PHP's shm_ functions work perfectly on my LINUX server but are not supported on Windows.  At present I am testing out my code on WAMP and using file_get/put_content as a local replacement for shm_attach etc but that is clumsy.  I gather that the shmp_ family of functions  are OS independent.  However when I try something simple like

```
<?php
$shm_key = 12879;
$shm_id = shmop_open($shm_key, "c", 0644, 100);
echo $shm_id;
?>
```

PHP complains that it does not know shmop_open.  I Googled around for an extension and found that shmop comes courtesy of a special PHP build.  I cannot possibly get into that here and now but I was wondering if it might be possible to find a ready build (Win 32) that has shmop activated so I can use it with Windows7 + WAMP.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of WAMP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On WAMP v2.2

- Left click on WAMP tray icon
- Select PHP -> PHP extensions
- scroll down to find `php_shmop` and enable it
- WAMP restarts

  you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't upgraded my WAMP installation in a while and it was still at v 2.0 with no shmop extension showing up on right click.  I upgraded and all is well.  Not the brightest question I have asked on this forum, I guess :-/